# Stopping a loop based on conditions

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

So I have a program that is supposed to calculate a running total. The user sets the maximum and then enters numbers between 1 and the maximum. If the user enters a negative number it's supposed to stop the loop and give the running total. I'm having an issue where it outputs the total and then continues to ask me for the next number. It also adds the negative number to the total which I don't want. I'm very new to python and any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
END = int(input('Enter a maximum value:'))
total = 0
correct = False
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and the maximum:'))
    total = total + number
    if number <= -1:
        print('Sum of all valid numbers entered:', total)
        correct = False
    elif number < 0 or number > END:
        print('Invalid number')
```

So I made some changes. I'm a little more confused. The code certainly stops at the point its supposed to but now it only returns the negative number entered.

```
END = int(input('Enter a maximum value:'))
total = 0
correct = False
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and the maximum:'))
    if number <= -1:
        total = total + number
        print('Sum of all valid numbers entered:', total)
        correct = False
        break
    elif number < 0 or number > END:
        print('Invalid number')
```

Comment: change `while True` to be `while correct` and you need to move the negative number check before you do `total = total + number`

Comment: Changing to while correct stopped the loop entirely, for some reason.

Comment: Please **debug** your program (you can start by using the [Visualizer](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html)), then you'll figure out what's happening. (See also: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Getting started with PyCharm debugger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJtWxm12Eo0))

Comment: I hadn't known how to use a debugger until your comment. Running the code through Visualizer helped me see how to use PyCharm's debugger. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: because `correct` starts as `False` when it should start as `True` @Neekolie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `break` to stop any loop without using any additional variables:

```
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and the maximum:'))
    total = total + number
    if number <= -1:
        print('Sum of all valid numbers entered:', total)
        break
    elif number < 0 or number > END:
        print('Invalid number')
```

And going on the code should be:

```
END = int(input('Enter a maximum value:'))
total = 0
while True:
    number = int(input('Enter a number between 1 and the maximum:'))
    if number <= -1:
        print('Sum of all valid numbers entered:', total)
        break
    elif number > END:
        print('Invalid number')
    else: # if the number is bigger than or equal 1
        total += number # total = total + number
```

Comment: Your answer got me the closest to making this code work. In conjunction with switching total =total + number to after the negative number check.. But now all it returns is the negative number itself.

Comment: 1. There is no need for `number < 0` in the elif because if the number is lower than 0 the first if statement (`if number <= -1`) will be executed

Comment: 2. You need to excute codes when the value is bigger than or equal 1 witch is the default situation

Comment: I've edited the answer please check it

Comment: That was it. I didn't know it was possible to put the total += number at the end in the else function, and if I'm honest I don't have my head wrapped around it. Thank you for your help. I get so mixed up in the nested loops, and the syntax is still blurry for me.

Comment: `total += number` is the same as `total = total + number`

Comment: I am here to explain anything

Comment: I wrote the end of the if statement (`else`) because you need to sum the numbers if the number is not bigger than the maximum value and not a nigative value

Comment: Holy guacamole. Now I understand. Else being the "catch-all" after all these conditions. <3333333

Comment: your mistake is you sum the numbers in `if number <= -1` and this will only sum the number if the number in negative and then it will break the loop witch will make total is a negative number (the last number you entered witch must be negative to break the loop)

Comment: yah exactly <33

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop a while loop you have to use the break statement.
So it will look like this

```
     total = total + number
     correct = False
     break
    elif
```